# Export default two functions in JS file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am working on reactJS and redux-saga project, I have a problem using the default export, I have a file like this :

```
import TYPE_CONTRAT_UPDATE from "./actionsTypes";
import { createAction } from "../../../../../../redux/Utilities";

const updateTypeContrat = (idContrat, data, success, error) =>
    createAction(TYPE_CONTRAT_UPDATE.PUT_CALL, { idContrat, data, success, 
error });
const updateConformiteContrat = (idContrat, data, success, error) => 
    createAction(CONFORMITE_PUT.PUT_CALL, { idContrat, data, success, error 
});

export default updateTypeContrat;
export default updateConformiteContrat;
```

But as you know I can not have two defaults in one file, is there any solution to this ? how can I make a default export to both ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

export default { updateTypeContrat, updateConformiteContrat }

import { updateTypeContrat, updateConformiteContrat } from './your-folder'

Answer (score 3):

There can only be one default export in a file. You can have other exports along with a default one like this.

```
import TYPE_CONTRAT_UPDATE from "./actionsTypes";
import { createAction } from "../../../../../../redux/Utilities";

const updateTypeContrat = (idContrat, data, success, error) =>
    createAction(TYPE_CONTRAT_UPDATE.PUT_CALL, { idContrat, data, success, 
error });
const updateConformiteContrat = (idContrat, data, success, error) => 
    createAction(CONFORMITE_PUT.PUT_CALL, { idContrat, data, success, error 
});

export default updateTypeContrat;
export {
  updateConformiteContrat
};
```

and import like this -

```
import updateTypeContrat from './<path>'
import { updateConformiteContrat } from './<path>'
```

Hope this helps !